# Using Tableview of a UISplitViewController as a filter

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm putting UISplitViewControllers in UITabBarController.

[image]

I'm Trying to use the master view as a filter. So I used cellAccessoryType as check mark . Only one among all can be selected. the code that i wrote for this is

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row

    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dispAccounts", sender: self)
        }
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = .None
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    filterList = ["All Accounts","Business Accounts","Person Accounts"]
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    //self.splitViewController?.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 140; //This line is to restrict the width of master View of UISplitVC
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 3
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("accountCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = filterList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Now Once I select 'All Account' cell,Then I move to another tab 'Call'
Then I comeback to 'Account' tab, then I select 'Business Accounts' it is getting selected and checkmark is also updating but the problem is 'All accounts' cell's check mark is not getting vanished.

Comment: Could you show the code you use in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Also, for your `UITableView`, do you have `allowsMultipleSelection` enabled? Do you want it enabled?

Comment: Have added the required code @Kumuluzz
Please have a look.
No. I don't want to allowMultipleSelection.
Even if I make it false the same problem is occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug occurs due to the optimisations that have been implemented into `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`. These two views are highly efficient and one way that Apple has made them so efficient is by reusing the cells instead of instantiating new cells all the time (that's why you are calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` instead of instantiating a new cell every time).

In order to overcome this bug, then you have to reset the cells every time they are used.

This can be done in two ways:

- Overwriting`prepareForReuse` if you were subclassing `UITableViewCell` (but this is not an option for you since you are using the standard `UITableViewCell`)
- Resetting the properties directly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

So a possible solution for you could look like the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Getting the cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("accountCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Resetting the cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = ""
    cell.selected = false

    // Configuring the cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = filterList[indexPath.row]

    // Returning the finished cell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Good Idea @Kumuluzz

Comment: But @Kumuluzz
After completely loading the table view then i'm selecting a cell.
so now It got selected and checkMark will be there.Then switch the tab and again switched back. Now, If I try to select another cell,it will also get selected,because the table view is not loading again at the time of switching back.

Comment: I also have tried. The Idea is not working. I think the problem is the table is not  getting reloaded when we switch the tabs. Please let me know if u get new idea's. Thanks

Comment: In the `viewWillAppear` of the controller, then call `tableView.reloadData()`